# Can't create contextMenu for listView item in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

To create menu when long click on each item on `ListView`. I created two scenarios:
Create `ContextMenu` on `Activtity` and `Fragment`.
However, It only run on `Activity` and not on `Fragment`.
The below is my code which implemented on fragment:

```
public class ContactTabFragment extends Fragment {

ListView listView;
List<Contact> listContacts;
ListVaultContactsAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container,
            false);
    initView(rootView);
    registerForContextMenu(listView);

    listContacts = VaultProviderUtil
                .getListOfVaultContacts(ContactTabFragment.this
                        .getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        adapter = new ListVaultContactsAdapter(
                ContactTabFragment.this.getActivity(), listContacts);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}

private void initView(View rootView) {
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listVaultContacts);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.a_item, Menu.NONE, "Menu A");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.b_item, Menu.NONE, "Menu B");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.c_item, Menu.NONE, "Menu C");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.d_item, Menu.NONE, "Menu D");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.e_item, Menu.NONE, "Menu E");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.f_item, Menu.NONE, "Menu F");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.a_item:
        Log.i("ContextMenu", "Item 1a was chosen");
        return true;
    case R.id.b_item:
        Log.i("ContextMenu", "Item 1b was chosen");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

I'm looking for the way to create Menu but still don't have any solution.
Please tell me how to solve it.
Thanks,

Comment: how many times do you register it for context menu? just do it in `onPostExecute` in your async task or better still in `onViewCreated()` in you Fragment lifecycle and see if it works

Comment: Sorrry, only one register for context Menu. I just edited my code as above but it still doesn't run as our exptectations. Do you have any suggestions for this ?

Comment: try registerForContextMenu after setAdapter() method.

Comment: Yes, I tried as your suggestion but not good ...:) I am still looking for a good solution...:):D

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that when you call to the:

```
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
```

You just call to the implementation of it in the Activity. Try to remove this line.

Edit: it explicitly written in docs:

> The default implementation calls up to Activity.onCreateContextMenu, though you can not call this implementation if you don't want that behavior.

Comment: What you mean by "it dosn't run"? Did you try to put BreakPoint in it and check what exactly happened?

Comment: Pay attention that if inside the adapter you take control on longClick behavior that mean that the  onCreateContextMenu won't call.

Comment: Sorry, I am looking for a solution for this but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: I tried as your suggesstions but doesn't have a good solution :(. Do you have any solution for this ?

Comment: Oh. it did work for you ? really ? Can you share what you do for this case ?

Comment: I just add to the Fragment like you did, and removed the super call. I added Log to see that it work. Try remove the adapter and see if you get the call to the context menu, because as I wrote to you if you take control of the longClick in the adapter the contextMenu won't call.